# Top 1 with where clause - ignore where clause if no record is found

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

What is the best way to select the first activity by date that isn't canceled, and if all activities are cancelled to select the first one.

**Scheme with sample data:**

```
create table SomeOtherTable
(
    Id bigint primary key
)

create table activities
(
  Id bigint identity(1,1) primary key,
  SomeForeignKey bigint,
  Description varchar(100),
  Date datetime,
  Canceled bit  
)


insert into SomeOtherTable values (1),(2),(3)

insert into activities values (1, 'Activity 1', '20141201', 1),
                              (1, 'Activity 2', '20141203', 0),
                              (1, 'Activity 3', '20141205', 0),
                              (2, 'Activity 4', '20141207', 1),
                              (2, 'Activity 5', '20141209', 1),
                              (3, 'Activity 6', '20141209', 0)
```

**Desired output:**

> Activity 2 - 2014/12/03 - 0
>
> Activity 4 - 2014/12/07 - 1
>
> Activity 6 - 2014/12/09 - 0

I'm currently using this query but I think there has to be a better solution...

```
select  case when a1.Id is null then a2.Description else a1.Description end as Description,
        case when a1.Id is null then a2.Date else a1.Date end as Date,
        case when a1.Id is null then a2.Canceled else a1.Canceled end as Canceled
from SomeOtherTable t
outer apply (select top 1 * 
             from activities a 
             where t.id=a.SomeForeignKey
             and a.Canceled = 0
             order by a.Date) a1

cross apply (select top 1 * 
             from activities a 
             where t.id=a.SomeForeignKey             
             order by a.Date) a2
```

[SQL Fiddle link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f0b3a/8/0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to prioritize the results, with `Canceled = 0` first and then any other row.  You can do this with a single `outer apply`:

```
select a.Description, a.Date, a.Canceled
from SomeOtherTable t outer apply
     (select top 1 * 
      from activities a 
      where t.id = a.SomeForeignKey
      order by (case when a.canceled = 0 then 1 else 0 end) desc, a.Date
     ) a;
```

I would normally put similar logic in a `row_number()` calculation, but `outer apply` works just as well.

EDIT:

For completeness and comparison, here is the `row_number()` method:

```
select a.Description, a.Date, a.Canceled
from SomeOtherTable t left join
     (select a.*,
             row_number() over (partition by a.SomeForeignKey
                                order by (case when a.canceled = 0 then 1 else 0 end) desc, a.Date
                               ) as seqnum
      from activities a 
     ) a
     on t.id = a.SomeForeignKey and seqnum = 1;
```

In general, I think the `apply` method is a wee bit faster -- essentially, it stops at the first matching row and doesn't need to keep processing for a give `t.id`.

Comment: This is actually makes sense... I was overcomplicating it. I tried it with the `row_number` too without succes tho. Thanks for this!